# k6 POST request receiving 401 unauthorized response when calling end point via Swagger

Tags: javascript, post, swagger, http-status-code-401, k6

The application itself is similar to Facebook where the user needs to log in and can access different features of the app, such as Marketplace.  I'm trying to run API performance tests on the application on a specific feature which calls a POST request.  The POST request can be found via Swagger, and I'm using I'm trying test run k6 performance metrics on that POST request, however I'm getting a 401 unauthorized error.  Here's my code:

```
import http from 'k6/http';
import { check } from 'k6';

export default async function getTransactions() {
    const res = http.get('https://xxxxxx.net/xxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxx/xxxx/action?email=xxxxx&password=xxxxxx');
    check(res, { 'status was 200': (r) => r.status == 200 });

    const url = 'https://xxxxxx/api/jr/txn/session/v1'
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        "atmId": [
            4
        ],
        "devtime0": 20231101000000,
        "devtime1": 20231111000000
  
    });
    const params = {
        headers: {
            'accept': '*/*',
            'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
            'content-type': 'application/json' ,
            'server': 'nginx/1.25.3',
        },
    };

    const transactionRes = http.post(url, payload, params)
    console.log(transactionRes.body);
    check(transactionRes, {'single transaction endpoint reached': (r) => r.status == 200});

}
```

I've tried getting authorization first with the GET call to the login page with the email and password needed to log in.  I was hoping the cookies received back from that session would give me authorization to test an API endpoint with a POST call.  I've been met with a 401 error instead however.  My next suspicion is that I need an API key or token to proceed further.  Would much appreciate guidance on how to proceed further with this!

Comment: Contact the API vendor and ask how to authenticate API calls, or check their API documentation if it's available.

Comment: @Helen I believe I need to send the session cookie I get from the first GET request with my POST request, but I'm not quite sure how to?

Comment: Are you sure that GET request actually returns a session cookie? It's unlikely that an API accepts the username and password via a URL query string because [it's insecure](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29600). Login requests are typically done using POST. I'm afraid it's impossible to answer your question without knowing which exactly API you're testing because different APIs use different types of auth. You should direct your questions to the API vendor.

Comment: @Helen So the GET request is to the application itself, and the response received should contain the session cookie after logging into the application.  The POST call is to the API which is a REST API.

Comment: @Helen I've asked the developers on the project, and the application uses Cookie as authentication